# Help ,clarify my doubt on Unqualified Name Lookup :ISO n3290 Draft

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces, c++11, scope

According to this link

[A point from C++0x draft : n3290](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120348/a-point-from-c0x-draft-n3290)

Shall this program is correct ?

```
EX:
namespace  X {};
enum Foo
  {
      X = 0,     #1
      Y,
      Z = X // X refers to the enum, not the type
  };
```

Iam getting error while execution this program like // #1 'X' redeclared as different kind of symbol

But in the above statement link  ...namespace scopes containing the enum-specifier. ...etc

please clarify my doubt.

Otherwise Please any one give me an example that proves the above statement(in link) with **namespace**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference in that the original question had a `struct X` instead of `namespace X`. The namespace name is visible in this scope, and so is Foo::X as enum names "leak" into the surrounding namespace. That creates a conflict.

In C (and therefore also in C++) the name of a struct/class/union is in a separate "tag namespace" (a C term with a different meaning) which allows us to declare another item using the same name in the same scope:

[Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: But with Struct X example it won't create an conflict acoording to the above ISO statement .but in terms of an namespace it is not working ... may i know the reason ...why ? please explain it

Comment: I thought I did that. :-) With a struct you are allowed to hide the name by declaring another one. You can always get at the struct anyway by writing `struct X`. This is inherited from C. Namespaces are a C++ feature and works differently.

Answer (score 0):

The program is illegal.  An `enum` does not introduce a separate scope
(unless you are using C++11 **and** add `class` to it), both the
namespace `X` and the enumeration constant `X` are in the same scope.
There are only two cases where the same name can be defined more than
once in the same scope: overloaded functions, and one class name.  The
special case for the class name is purely for C compatibility, so that
C API's with functions like:

```
struct stat { ... };
int stat(const char* path, struct stat* buf);
```

wouldn't break.  If both a class name and another name are present, the
other name has precedence, unless preceded by a class keyword.

Comment: Note, in C++11, you don't need `enum class` for enumerators to have scope. They always have scope with the enumeration name (assuming they have an enumeration name). But, for backwards compatibility, they retain their old scope. So `Y` and `Foo::Y` would both be legal in C++11.